# How to capture logs of jar file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, logging

I have a nodejs code like below

```
try{
   call someShellScript.sh
}
catch(error)
{
console.log('error is '+error)
}
```

In someShellScript.sh, a jar file abc.jar is run. I am able to see some output lines from jar file execution in the console. But I am not able to capture them lets say to a variable. My requirement is to capture the error while executing logic present in jar file. Try catch is not helping here. Also, I cannot edit the java code and rebuild the jar file. But I would need to capture the output of jar file execution somehow in Nodejs and in case of errors while executing logic inside jar file, I need to take certain actions based on the error. So, can someone help me on how to capture the output of jar file in nodejs.

Comment: Redirect output to a file and read that file?

Comment: Ho @DavidConrad, due to limitation in no. of characters in a comment, I have posted a new question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419884/capture-console-output-of-shellscript-in-nodejs]. Would be great if you can take a look at it and suggest.